# How do I call a function when the mouse goes up above a goog.ui.Control?

Tags: google-closure, google-closure-library

I tried to call a function when a mouse goes up above a subclass of `goog.ui.Control`:

```
/** @override */
myapp.MyButton.prototype.handleMouseUp =
    function(e) {
  goog.base(this, 'handleMouseUp', e);
  alert('Woof!');
}
```

However, when I click on my button, not alert shows up. Why not? Doesn't `handleMouseUp` get called when my mouse is raised after a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for `goog.ui.Control` contains the following comment:

> All controls dispatch SHOW, HIDE, ENTER, LEAVE, and ACTION events on show, hide, mouseover, mouseout, and user action, respectively.

To see exactly which events are dispatched for various actions, take a look at the **[goog.ui.Control demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/control.html)**, which has a live event log.

In order to enable addition transition events, `goog.ui.Control` includes the following method:

```js
/**
 * Enables or disables transition events for the given state(s).  Controls
 * handle state transitions internally by default, and only dispatch state
 * transition events if explicitly requested to do so by calling this method.
 * @param {number} states Bit mask of {@link goog.ui.Component.State}s for
 *     which transition events should be enabled or disabled.
 * @param {boolean} enable Whether transition events should be enabled.
 */
goog.ui.Control.prototype.setDispatchTransitionEvents = function(states,
    enable) {
  this.statesWithTransitionEvents_ = enable ?
      this.statesWithTransitionEvents_ | states :
      this.statesWithTransitionEvents_ & ~states;
};
```

For example, you could do the following to enable transition events for all states.

```js
var myButton = new myapp.MyButton();
myButton.setDispatchTransitionEvents(goog.ui.Component.State.ALL, true);
```

Now when the mouse button is down the `activate` event will be dispatched and upon releasing the mouse button the `deactivate` event will be dispatched.

See the **[goog.ui.Button demo](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/button.html)** (in particular, the combined toggle buttons near the bottom of the page).